# Price change from quantity

Tags: php, html

Hi I've written a simple form math setup but I realized it needs to change, Basically what I need to create is something to detect that if Adult tickets is 10 or greater each ticket costs $7 not the $10, but if its 9 or under each ticket will still be $10

```html
<form name="newshow" id="newshow" action="test.php" method="post" 
    oninput="totalamount.value = Math.round(adult.value * 10) 
 + Math.round(student.value * 7); changedue.value = 
 Math.round(moneygiven.value - totalamount.value);">
        <fieldset>
            <select name="showtime" >
                <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Performance</option>
                <option value='1' type="number" >Show 1 </option>
                <option value='2' type="number" >Show 2 </option>
                <option value='3' type="number" >Show 3 </option>
            </select>
            <h4>Ammount of Adults</h4>
                <input name="adult" id="adult" type="number" >
            <br />
            <h4>Ammount of Students</h4>
                <input name="student" type="number" >
            <br />
            <h4>Money Owed</h4>
                <input name="totalamount" readonly="1">
            <br />
            <h4>Money Given</h4>
                <input name="moneygiven" type="number" >
            <h4>Change due</h4>
                <input name="changedue" readonly="1">
                <input type="submit" />
        </fieldset>
  </form>
```

I'm not sure where to go from here but I'm assuming this would be done with a script and not with the "oninput" that I currently am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. this will check if adult ticket is >= 10

```html
<form name="newshow" id="newshow" action="test.php" method="post" 
oninput="totalamount.value =  ((adult.value >= 10) ? Math.round(adult.value * 7) : Math.round(adult.value * 10))  + Math.round(student.value * 7); 
changedue.value = Math.round(moneygiven.value - totalamount.value);">
    <fieldset>
        <select name="showtime" >
            <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Performance</option>
            <option value='1' type="number" >Show 1 </option>
            <option value='2' type="number" >Show 2 </option>
            <option value='3' type="number" >Show 3 </option>
        </select>
        <h4>Ammount of Adults</h4>
            <input name="adult" id="adult" type="number" >
        <br />
        <h4>Ammount of Students</h4>
            <input name="student" type="number" >
        <br />
        <h4>Money Owed</h4>
            <input name="totalamount" readonly="1">
        <br />
        <h4>Money Given</h4>
            <input name="moneygiven" type="number" >
        <h4>Change due</h4>
            <input name="changedue" readonly="1">
            <input type="submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: ah yes this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!!